# Vanilla JavaScript click event run twice but i click one time

Tags: javascript, foreach, onclick

Can someone help me with this:I'm making a advanced to do list for practice with JS but i'm getting an error when i have to remove items from list and there are only two items left i remove the second one and the click event run two times but the code works only i get one error because click event run two times.This happen and when 1 item wos left but when i have more than 2 items and i click to remove them event run normally.**Another thing that i want to mention is that inside a button i have set an svg that has this click event that runs two times**

```
hiqBtn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
let arrPerMinus = []; //after pushing elements to this array

 arrPerMinus.forEach(el => { //for each el i add an event listner
        el.addEventListener('click',e =>{//**Also i want to mention that el's are svg's**
           //then i run code inside

    })
  })
}
```

Im expectiing only not to get error because the code is working but only trying to make the click event not run twice

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: on every btn click you add another event listener to your minus element. don't do that. Add the click event only once (when you create the element)

Comment: To fix this, you can try removing the event listener before registering it again. As for the click event being triggered twice on the SVGs, it's possible that the SVG element is nested inside another element that also has a click event listener. You can try adding e.stopPropagation() inside the click event listener for the SVG to prevent the event from bubbling up to its parent elements.

Comment: @Stefan thanks i found the problem im adding the same click event in the same element

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue and tried the solution Mohammed suggested but it didn't really work with my code, so I tried  :

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

instead of :

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

try calling `e.stopPropagation();`, By calling this your click event will only trigger once for each element in the arrPerMinus array.

```
hiqBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let arrPerMinus = []; //after pushing elements to this array

  arrPerMinus.forEach(el => { //for each el i add an event listner
    el.addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      // run code inside
    })
  })
})
```

Hope This Helps....